# CYPHER cumulative counting of related nodes

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j instance and I'm using CYPHER to do the following:

I want to create a cumulative count query. I have the following structure:

[image: node structure]

Ideally I want an output like this:

- Computer, count: **3**
- Physical Sciences, count: **4** (because computer has 3 and the node itself has 1)
- ..... for all other nodes

Basically the purple nodes needs to count the blue-ish ones.

I have done a simple query that would count the number for each one, but how to accumulate all the results.

My sample query is:

```sql
MATCH (n:Field) WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:RELATES_TO {predicate: 'has field'}]->(n) WITH n, p
RETURN n.my_id AS field_id, n.label AS field, COUNT(p) AS num
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer...

```
MATCH (n:Field)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:RELATES_TO*0..2 {predicate: 'has field'}]->(:Field)<-[:RELATES_TO {predicate: 'has field'}]-(p:Blue)
RETURN n.my_id AS field_id, n.label AS field, count(p) AS num
```

And you should identify the second label of the node you want to count (it might not be a `Field` after all.

And you need to make the degrees away varaible but it should be constrained at some depth, for instance `..2`.

Find all the `Field` that `RELATE_TO` `Blue` (made up that label, I did not see it in your example) at most two hops away and return the counts per field.

```
MATCH (n:Field)-[:RELATES_TO*..2]->(p:Blue)
RETURN n.my_id AS field_id, n.label AS field, count(p) AS num
```

Or if you want all of the fields even

```
MATCH (n:Field)
OPTIOANL MATCH (n)-[:RELATES_TO*..2]->(p:Blue)
RETURN n.my_id AS field_id, n.label AS field, count(p) AS num
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but actually the direction of the relation is correct. I have the same relation but different properties on the relation it self to distinguish. the `[:RELATES_TO*..2]` part is helpful I guess. But I still need to apply a condition on the relation to make sure it works